# trying to display static block for category—will only display category view

Tags: layout, static-block

I’m trying to set up a static block for my categories. I created a phtml file, then linked this file to the static block I created:

```
{{block type="catalog/navigation" template="catalog/navigation/sub_navigation.phtml"}}
```

Then I went the Cataglog->Manage Categories and selected"Static Block Only” under Display Setting->Display mode. I selected the static block I just created.

However, when I navigate to that category on my site, it just displays the regular category view (the layout I created under template->category->view.phtml in my template folder).

Any idea what I’m doing wrong here? I tried re-indexing everything, to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First test with anything else, remove the `{{block}}` from the CMS block and write something in it, does it work?

## If no

then you have a problem with the view of ANY block. Check your `app/design/frontend/<base>/<default>/template/catalog/category/view.phtml` for this entry:

```
<?php if($this->isContentMode()): ?>
    <?php echo $this->getCmsBlockHtml() ?>

<?php elseif($this->isMixedMode()): ?>
    <?php echo $this->getCmsBlockHtml() ?>
    <?php echo $this->getProductListHtml() ?>

<?php else: ?>
    <?php echo $this->getProductListHtml() ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

## If yes

Something with your block is wrong or with the template. Check the template and the `system.log` for errors

Comment: Thank you! With your help, I've made some progress. I added your code in my view.phtml file. Now, instead of the category list, I get a blank page (save for the title). When I specify a DIFFERENT static block (just some footer links), it works (displays the footer links). When I replace all of the php code in the sub_navigation.phtml file with just a "hey there", it still doesn't display it (which makes me think there's something wrong with the specified path to file, rather than the file itself). I will continue to research.

Comment: Ah -- I had to delete the "name" attribute I had added to the `{{block...` code (when I was trying out different tactics to get it to work). It's working now...thanks!